# C++ factorial function must return -1 if zero or 1 is entered as a parameter

Tags: c++, function

I am writing a factorial function in c++. I have the function working fine. However on of the requirements is that the function must calculate, and return, the factorial of the number provided to it (its parameter) if the
parameter is positive. If it receives a parameter which is negative or zero, the function must return -1. 
I can't seem to get it to return the -1 for zero or negative number without it also returning a negative number for the normal factorial calculations. here is my code so far.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long factorial(int x)
{

if(x>1)
    return (x*factorial(x-1));  
else 
    return -1;

}

int main()
{
int number;
cout << "Enter a number: " << endl;
cin >> number;
cout << factorial(number);
cout << endl;

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Switch the if/else statement order. Check for 0/1 first and return -1 else calculate factorial

Comment: 12! is the largest factorial that fits in a 32-bit integer. Anything larger will overflow and is likely to give you a negative result.

Comment: @jrok Is not it `0` starting from `34!`? (Otherwise I'd expect about _half_ results to be negative.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two base cases:

```
if (x <= 1) return -1
if (x == 2) return 2
else do the recursion
```

But this is mathematically incorrect. The factorial of 1 and 0 is 1.

Comment: If I read the title correctly, even `1!` should result in `-1`.

Comment: Note that the text of the question agrees with your first version.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Well, I'll leave that for the OP to sort out. The important part of my answer is the 2 base cases.

Comment: so I messed up the actual question the factorial of 1 should read as 1 not -1. This code works for everything else. I tried changing the if statement to if(x <= 0) return -1, but this still returns -1 for 1! any advice?

Comment: @JoshNicolet: What is your second base case? If your first base case is checking for `x <= 0`, then your second one should be checking for `x == 1` (and should return 1, in that case).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: thanks that is what I just did. It is now properly working. I appreciate your input

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your function:

```
long _factorial(int arg){
    if(x>1)
        return (x*factorial(x-1));  
    else 
        return 1;
}

inline long factorial(int arg){
    return (arg<=0)?-1:_factorial(arg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think I got it. the factorial of 1 did actually need to be 1 not -1. My professor wanted zero and any negative number to return -1. Thank you to everyone for your response.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long factorial(int x)
{

if(x<=0)
    return -1;
if(x == 1)
    return 1;
if(x==2)
    return 2;   
else  
    return (x*factorial(x-1));

}
```

Comment: The factorial of zero is in fact equal to `1`.

Comment: The third base case (`if(x==2)`) is redundant.

Comment: Any "else" after "if" with "return" is also redundant.